# adding a subdomain that points a different server

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

Currently my web application is running on Amazon ec2 server on a Tomcat web server . 
My domain example.com is hosted on godaddy which points to the Amazon server ip.

I have a static website ready for integration ( html , css js files)
The problem: I want to separate the static website from the web-application. 
to do so I hired a freelancer who has already provided me the html, css and js files. 
Now I need to do the following:
pointing example.com --> server A
pointing app.example.com --> server B

I was trying to add a subdomain app.example.com on godaddyy that will point a different url. That didnt work , so I assumed that I would need to defined it in the Amazon route 53.  I added hosted zone with an A record to app.example.com that will point a certain ip. It didn't work too .....

Comment: *I was trying to add a subdomain app.example.com on godaddyy that will point a different url. That didnt work*  What does "didn't work" mean? In what sense did it not work?  It should have worked.

Comment: After a multiple trials I managed to make it somehow work. The thing is that I shouldn't have add a hosted zone but just add a CNAME record to the existing hostzone.